# Local Folders to Github Repos

Tags: git, github

I have a bunch of folders that contain projects. I would love to put them all on github, but the process is very slow as I have to make a new repo, then add the files, etc. Is there anyway that I can do this process in bulk?

Answer (score 0):

You could use GitHub's client which does it all by itself, the interface is quite simple and doesn't require any command line action.

[GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/)

[GitHub for Mac](https://mac.github.com/)

The process itself only involves pressing one or two buttons, naming the repository and it uploads the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the repos created on the GitHub side, i.e. you have pressed "new repository" and you've an empty repo, you could script it. Something like (assuming your folders are in `./`):

```
for dir in $(ls *); do
  pushd $dir &&
  git init &&
  git add . &&
  git commit -m 'Initial commit' &&
  git remote add origin git@github.com/<you>/$dir.git &&
  git push -u origin HEAD &&
  popd
done
```